# How to test type of range parameter in Google Spreadsheet script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just starting tinkering with scripts for Google Spreadsheet and I have a problem :

How to test if the type of a function's parameter is a range of cells ?

I'd like to do something like this :

```
if(typeof intput != "range") {
  throw "input must be a range";
}
```

From Google's examples [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions) (middle of the page) :

```
if (typeof inNum != "number") {  // check to make sure input is a number
  throw "input must be a number";  // throw an exception with the error message
}
```

So this seems to be the right way to test the type of a variable. But I don't know how to test if the type is a range of cells.

It'd be even better if I could specify if the range is one or two dimensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A range of cells is just a Array (multidimensional array)
Javascript has a problem in that way. Array's are seen as an object.
So first check if you have the "object" type and then you could test like this.

```
if(typeof intput=="object"&&intput.length!=undefined) {
  //input is a array
}else{
  //Not a array
}
```

By testing a default property you can determine for certain that you have a array

Comment: Thank you it works. I got it to check for one-dimensional range like this : `if(input.length != undefined && input[0].length == undefined)` and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

A range may represent a single cell (e.g. `'A1'`) or group of cells (e.g. `'A1:A2'`).

A range is converted into a range value when it is passed as a custom function parameter (e.g. `=processRangeVal(A1:A2)`).

If the range is a single cell then the range value is simply the data in that cell.

If the range is a group of cells then the range value is a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is the rows and the second dimension the columns in each row.

To test for the range value representing a cell vs a group of cells:

```js
function processRangeVal(rangeVal) {
  if (Array.isArray(rangeVal[0])) {
    // do 2d-array handling
  } else {
    // do cell data handling
  }
}
```

`rangeVal[0]` resolves to `undefined` if the range is a single cell and the cell data does not support indexing. In this case `Array.isArray(undefined)` resolves to false which is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

I know its really old post but I have a solution.

Firtly you need to know those:

- getCell() is a **range** object method
- isSheetHidden() is a **sheet** method
- getSpreadsheetTheme() is a **spreadsheet** method

now we will take advantage of it:

first write extention method for all spesific object type:

```
Object.prototype.isRange = function () { return this.getCell !== undefined }
Object.prototype.isSheet = function () { return this.isSheetHidden != undefined }
Object.prototype.isSpreadsheet = function () { return this.getSpreadsheetTheme != undefined }
```

now you can test:

```
function myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("FOOD_DB")
  let range = sheet.getActiveRange()

  Logger.log("range.isRange(): " + range.isRange())             //TRUE
  Logger.log("range.isSheet(): " + range.isSheet())             //false
  Logger.log("range.isSpreadsheet(): " + range.isSpreadsheet()) //false

  Logger.log("sheet.isRange(): " + sheet.isRange())             //false
  Logger.log("sheet.isSheet(): " + sheet.isSheet())             //TRUE
  Logger.log("sheet.isSpreadsheet(): " + sheet.isSpreadsheet()) //false

  Logger.log("ss.isRange(): " + ss.isRange())                   //false
  Logger.log("ss.isSheet(): " + ss.isSheet())                   //false
  Logger.log("ss.isSpreadsheet(): " + ss.isSpreadsheet())       //TRUE

}
```